# How to make a cell equal THE FIRST THREE LINES of another cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to make one cell the same as the first three lines of another cell. I'm having issues on doing this.

The closest I've gotten is this, but it only pulls the first line.
=LEFT(B2, FIND(char(10), B2))

=LEFT(B2, FIND(char(10), B2))

For example, if I wanted to extract:

Ooh whoa, ooh whoa, ooh whoa 
 
You know you love me, I know you care 
 
Just shout whenever and I'll be there 
 
You are my love, you are my heart 
 
And we will never, ever, ever be apart

The end result would be:

Ooh whoa, ooh whoa, ooh whoa 
 
You know you love me, I know you care 
 
Just shout whenever and I'll be there

Comment: Perhaps `=LEFT(B2,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(B2,CHAR(10),CHAR(1),3)&CHAR(1))-1)`

Comment: Agghhhgh you're amazing! Thanks! It worked!

Comment: @tigeravatar why do you not post this as an answer? You seem to post formulas only in comments. Why?

Comment: @teylyn Mostly because I generally consider formulas low effort and so a comment is all that's needed instead of an in-depth answer.  But I know that for future users searching stack overflow if a question doesn't have an answer posted it could get passed over (even though there's an answer in the comments), so I'll add these as answers like I really should be doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps:

`=LEFT(B2,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(B2,CHAR(10),CHAR(1),3)&CHAR(1))-1)`